# Using RegQueryValueEx for a registry value that could be REG_DWORD or REG_SZ

Tags: c++, windows, registry

Currently I am using `RegQueryValueEx()` to retrieve a registry value that could potentially be written in either a `REG_SZ` or `REG_DWORD` format.

```
BYTE byteArray[MAX];
DWORD dataSize = sizeof(byteArray);
DWORD type = 0;
RegQueryValueEx(
        hKey,
        subKey,
        nullptr,
        &type,
        reinterpret_cast<BYTE*>(&byteArray),
        &dataSize));
```

When I get the data of a `REG_SZ` value (example: "42314"), I get this in response:

```
byteArray   0x004fe6a8 "4"  unsigned char[100]
    [0] 52 '4'  unsigned char
    [1] 0 '\0'  unsigned char
    [2] 50 '2'  unsigned char
    [3] 0 '\0'  unsigned char
    [4] 51 '3'  unsigned char
    [5] 0 '\0'  unsigned char
    [6] 49 '1'  unsigned char
    [7] 0 '\0'  unsigned char
    [8] 52 '4'  unsigned char
    [9] 0 '\0'  unsigned char
    [10]0 '\0'  unsigned char
```

Is there any way I could not have the null bytes after every character? I think it is because of [`RegEnumValue()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724911.aspx) being called for each character, but I am not sure.

Comment: about what you asking ?

Comment: It's Unicode UTF16-LE ending with a 16bit 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue has nothing to do with `RegEnumValue()`.

Your app is calling the `TCHAR`-based `RegQueryValueEx()`, which is actually a preprocessor macro that maps to either `RegQueryValueExA()` (ANSI) or `RegQueryValueExW()` (Unicode), depending on whether `UNICODE` is defined at compile-time.

`RegQueryValueExW()` returns string data as Unicode text in UTF-16LE format, which is exactly what you are seeing in your buffer, so clearly your app is being compiled for Unicode.  What you are seeing is perfectly normal behavior.

So, you need to handle string data in the format it is given to you, eg:

```
BYTE byteArray[MAX];
DWORD dataSize = sizeof(byteArray);
DWORD type = 0;
if (RegQueryValueEx( // <-- calling the TCHAR version!
    hKey,
    subKey,
    nullptr,
    &type,
    reinterpret_cast<BYTE*>(&byteArray),
    &dataSize) == 0)
{
    switch (type)
    {
        case REG_DWORD:
        {
            LPDWORD value = reinterpret_cast<LPDWORD>(&byteArray);
            // use *value as needed ...
            break;
        }

        case REG_SZ:
        case REG_MULTI_SZ:
        case REG_EXPAND_SZ:
        {
            // note the T in LPTSTR!  That means 'TCHAR' is used...
            LPTSTR text = reinterpret_cast<LPTSTR>(&byteArray);
            // use text as needed, up to (dataSize/sizeof(TCHAR)) number
            // of TCHARs. This is because RegQueryValueEx() does not
            // guarantee the output data has a null terminator.  If you
            // want that, use RegGetValue() instead...
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Or:

```
BYTE byteArray[MAX];
DWORD dataSize = sizeof(byteArray);
DWORD type = 0;
if (RegQueryValueExW( // <-- calling the UNICODE version!
    hKey,
    subKey,
    nullptr,
    &type,
    reinterpret_cast<BYTE*>(&byteArray),
    &dataSize) == 0)
{
    switch (type)
    {
        case REG_DWORD:
        {
            LPDWORD value = reinterpret_cast<LPDWORD>(&byteArray);
            // use *value as needed ...
            break;
        }

        case REG_SZ:
        case REG_MULTI_SZ:
        case REG_EXPAND_SZ:
        {
            // note the W in LPWSTR!  That means 'WCHAR' is used...
            LPWSTR text = reinterpret_cast<LPWSTR>(&byteArray);
            // use text as needed, up to (dataSize/sizeof(WCHAR)) number
            // of WCHARs. This is because RegQueryValueExW() does not
            // guarantee the output data has a null terminator.  If you
            // want that, use RegGetValueW() instead...
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

If you want the text in another format, you will have to either:

1. convert it after reading it as Unicode, such as with `WideCharToMultiByte()` or equivilent.
2. use `RegQueryValueExA()` (or `RegGetValueA()`) directly, which will return string data as ANSI text in the user's current locale, per the documentation:

   > If the data has the `REG_SZ`, `REG_MULTI_SZ` or `REG_EXPAND_SZ` type, and the ANSI version of this function is used (either by explicitly calling `RegQueryValueExA` or by not defining `UNICODE` before including the `Windows.h` file), this function converts the stored Unicode string to an ANSI string before copying it to the buffer pointed to by `lpData`.

   ```
   BYTE byteArray[MAX];
   DWORD dataSize = sizeof(byteArray);
   DWORD type = 0;
   if (RegQueryValueExA( // <-- calling the ANSI version
       hKey,
       subKey,
       nullptr,
       &type,
       reinterpret_cast<BYTE*>(&byteArray),
       &dataSize) == 0)
   {
       switch (type)
       {
           case REG_DWORD:
           {
               LPDWORD value = reinterpret_cast<LPDWORD>(&byteArray);
               // use *value as needed ...
               break;
           }

           case REG_SZ:
           case REG_MULTI_SZ:
           case REG_EXPAND_SZ:
           {
               // note the lack of T in LPSTR! That means 'char' is used...
               LPSTR text = reinterpret_cast<LPSTR>(&byteArray);
               // use text as needed, up to dataSize number of chars. This
               // is because RegQueryValueExA() does not guarantee the
               // output data has a null terminator.  If you want that,
               // use RegGetValueA() instead...
               break;
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Either way, just note that you will run the risk of losing any non-ASCII characters that do not exist in the target charset you decide to convert to.  So, better to stick with Unicode instead, and handle the buffer data as `WCHAR` data (what `TCHAR` maps to when `UNICODE` is defined).

Comment: Awesome! I actually wanted to store it back as a DWORD so right now i'm converting it from
    `LPDWORD value = reinterpret_cast<LPDWORD>(&byteArray);`
    `DWORD output = _ttoi(value);` If there's a more efficient way please let me know! I'm not too familiar with these types of conversions

Comment: You can't cast a `REG_SZ` buffer to an `LPDWORD` pointer (well, you can, but it won't be meaningful), and you can't pass an `LPDWORD` pointer to `_ttoi()`, as it expects a null-terminated `TCHAR*` pointer instead. And `RegQueryValueEx()` does not guarantee a null terminator will be present in the output buffer.  So, use `RegGetValue()` instead, and then you can use `LPTSTR text = reinterpret_cast<LPTSTR>(&byteArray); DWORD value = _ttoi(text);`

Answer (score 0):

```
Example showing opening/creating key, setting value, and finally querying it.
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <atlbase.h>

void MessageIDs_RegistryAdd() {
  LONG nError = 0;
  HKEY ROOT_KEY = HKEY_CURRENT_USER;
  HKEY hOpenKey = 0;
  char *strKey = "Software\\AKey\\AnotherKey";

  // Open Key
  nError = RegOpenKeyEx( ROOT_KEY, strKey, NULL, KEY_ALL_ACCESS, &hOpenKey );
  if (nError == ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND) {
    // Create Key
    nError = RegCreateKeyEx( ROOT_KEY, strKey, NULL, NULL, REG_OPTION_NON_VOLATILE,KEY_ALL_ACCESS, NULL, &hOpenKey, NULL);
    }
  if ( nError != ERROR_SUCCESS ) {
    OutputDebugString("  Error opening/creating key\r\n");
    return;
    } 

  // Set Key Value
  DWORD dwValue = 42;
  nError = RegSetValueEx( hOpenKey, NULL, 0, REG_DWORD, (const BYTE*)&dwValue, sizeof(dwValue) );
  if ( nError != ERROR_SUCCESS ) {
    OutputDebugString("  Error setting key value\r\n");
    return;
    }

  // Read Key
  const int MAX = 4096;
  DWORD type = REG_DWORD;
  DWORD dataSize = sizeof(DWORD);
  DWORD theVal = 0;
  nError = RegQueryValueEx( hOpenKey, NULL, nullptr, &type, reinterpret_cast<BYTE*>(&theVal), &dataSize );
  if ( nError != ERROR_SUCCESS ) {
    OutputDebugString("  Error reading key value\r\n");
    return;
    }

  // Close key
  nError = RegCloseKey( hOpenKey );
  if ( nError != ERROR_SUCCESS ) {
    OutputDebugString("  Error closing key.");
    return;
    }

  return;
  }

// Darryl Bassett
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).